# Would re-importing reduce the DB/backup size?

Tags: mariadb

My MariaDB DB size is constantly growing. So is the backup file size.

As I am not a DB admin (just a programmer using this DB) I wonder if I could just export the whole DB, then delete the existing one and re-import it again to decrease its size/backup size?

Idea: I wonder if this would reduce the overall size as all update and change operations would be no longer in the changelog. Some of the increased size can be explained by the number of tuples (growing over time), but I have also tables which have a lot of insert delete operations.

Maybe I am completely naive, but I wonder if this would work?

--- edit ----

As asked below, I create the dump with `mysqldump` ("my backup") and import it with `source mydumfile.sql`

Comment: Define "backup size" -- what kind of backup?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  It depends.

Long answer:

It depends on what Engine you are using.

It depends on the value of `innodb_file_per_table` when you created the tables.

It depends on whether you have inserted about as many rows as you have deleted.

It depends on what you mean by "changelog".

It depends on what you do to clear the disk space between the dump and the reload.

But most likely the answer is:  The disk footprint won't shrink any, or at least not much.

YMMV -- Try it.

Answer (score 1):

> As I am not a DB admin (just a programmer using this DB) I wonder if I could just export the whole DB, then delete the existing one and re-import it again to decrease its size/backup size?

You could always ask the DBA!

With the best Will in the World, it's *not your responsiblity* to ensure that the database is properly managed, recoverable (backed up), maintained (with house-keeping runs) and so on ...   it's *theirs*!

Also, if we're *not* talking about a Development database here, I would be deeply concerned if you even had the *permissions* to drop and recreate a database.  Again, not your responsibility.

All that said:

No; dumping and reloading the database probably won't make a lot of difference to the overall size *unless* you've been deleting a *lot* of data from your tables.  Databases do a good job of filling in the "holes" that deletions make but they're by no means perfect.  Reorganising a table *can* get you some space gains, but probably not much.